# How to upload project from local file system to GitLab

Tags: upload, gitlab

I have locally developed an application using Laravel Framework and PhpStorm. So, in the file system of my pc I have the project that I want to upload in a repository created in GitLab.

I have to mention that for development purposes I am currently using Homestead in windows with Vagrant virtual machine.

I already have an account in GitLab and for now I have only created a README file.

What are the necessary steps in order to upload my project in GitLab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can create new project **without** Initialize repository with a README file.

and follow "Push an existing folder" look like:

#### Push an existing folder

```
cd existing_folder
git init --initial-branch=main
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:youraccount/project_name.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know if everything went ok. Thanks in advance

Comment: After executing the command 'git push -u origin main', I am facing this error message: "fatal: protocol 'git@gitlab.com:https' is not supported". Do you know how to fix this? I have to mention that I am using Git Bash to execute the commands.

Comment: I managed to pass through the above error by using the url for my repository that need SSH. Now, I am facing with 'Connection timed out fatal: Could not read from remote repository. GitLab' error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Tinxuanna, you have to create repo in gitlab

Answer (score 3):

1. You have to create a new repository. Use the following command to create an a Git repository. It can be used to convert an existing, unversioned project to a Git repository or initialize a new, empty repository.  A .git folder is created in your directory. This folder contains Git records and configuration files. You should not edit these files directly.

```
git init
```

2. If you want to add the files to track with git then you need to use`git add` command. if you want to add new or modified or deleted files in the current directory. then add . to select all the files.

```
git add .
```

3. git commit creates a snapshot of the changes made to a Git repository which can then be pushed to the main repository. The -m option of the commit command lets you write the commit message.

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

4. You add a “remote” to tell Git which remote repository in GitLab is tied to the specific local folder on your computer. The remote tells Git where to push or pull from. You have to create a project to hold your files.
   **You should create a project in gitlab.that path should be given in the following command.**

```
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:username/projectpath.git
```

5. Get the changes from the remote with `git pull`

```
git pull origin master
```

6. Push the commits to the GitLab project

```
git push origin master
```

If any problem occurs in pushing use the following command for force push
 `git push --force origin master`

Comment: Thank you @RCvaram for your analytical answer. Following the instructions above and using the internal network where the GitLab connection has been set up (university network), I managed to upload the project.

Comment: Hope, It somehow helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd existing_repo
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/yourname/yourproject.git
git branch -M main
git push -uf origin main
```

Then if you face the common error that goes like:

```
remote rejected main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Do the following

Login to your Gitlab account 
Select Your Project
Click the Settings menu
Click the Repository menu
Click Protected Branches
Toggle Allow to force push

Note: You may decide who should have such access (maintainers, Developers or both)

Answer (score 0):

if you are uploading a new project for the first time. After creation you can clone the project then upload.
1.at first git init
git init
2.Git add`git add .`
3.commit `git commit -m "message"`
4.pull is good practice `git pull origin main`
5. then you can push the project `git push -u origin main`